# Error in generating QR code from chillerlan php-qrcode

Tags: php

I am trying to create a QR code from chillerlan/php-qrcode library found on github. I have successfully followed all the steps and installed composer by command

```
composer require chillerlan/php-qrcode
```

after executing this command composor.json , composor.lock and vendor name folder created and then I have created a index.php page in the root folder where vendor and both 2 file present inside the index page the code is

```
<?php
use chillerlan\QRCode\QRCode;
$text = 'Hello, world!';
$qrcode = new QRCode();
echo $qrcode->render($text);
?>
```

But after executing this index.php on localhost it gives error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "chillerlan\QRCode\QRCode" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\qr\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\qr\index.php on line 4

My PHP version is 8.1.12

.

Comment: Package requires php7.4 or 8.0 version. Reference: https://github.com/chillerlan/php-qrcode#installation

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the **Vendor Autoload**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Please explain to OP what it is for.